# is there any way change the spaces between words of text in text view

Tags: java, android, textview

```js
public void fullGhazal(Integer jk) {
        ghazalLayout.removeAllViews();

        Cursor data = dataBaseHelper.getghazalut(jk);
        if (data.getCount() != 0 && data.moveToFirst()) {


            String title = data.getString(0);
            str1 = data.getString(1);
            Spannable spannable = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(str1);
            String str2 = spannable.toString();

            //checking split text option

            String[] replace = str1.split("\n\n");

            int length = replace.length;


            expandableTextViews = new com.urdushairiclassics.shairykeustad.Utils.ExpandableTextView[length];


            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );


            for (kh = 0; kh < length; kh++) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                String huzefa = replace[kh];

                Spannable spannable1 = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(huzefa);

                expandableTextViews[kh] = (com.urdushairiclassics.shairykeustad.Utils.ExpandableTextView) View.inflate(this, R.layout.expandabletextviews, null);
                View viewDivider = new View(this);
                int dividerHeight = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 1); // 1dp to pixels
                viewDivider.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        dividerHeight
                ));
                viewDivider.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);


                expandableTextViews[kh].setText((CharSequence) spannable1);
                expandableTextViews[kh].setTag(sherCount);
                expandableTextViews[kh].setId(kh);
                expandableTextViews[kh].setTextSize(2, this.textSize);

                expandableTextViews[kh].setTypeface(AppUtils.getTypeFace(getAssets()));
                expandableTextViews[kh].setLayoutParams(params);
                ghazalLayout.addView(expandableTextViews[kh]);
                ghazalLayout.addView(viewDivider);


            }
```

**Text displayed in my app:**
[image: text displayed in my app]

**How I want to display it:**
[image: i want to display it like]

I am using custom **TextView** to show the data fetched from database. Text displayed not being aligned properly. I have attached image so that you people can better understand the problem.

Comment: We had similar questions several hours ago. You ask again that question?!

Comment: comment the link of that question. did someone solve it

Comment: It was about 12 hours ago, see android questions

Comment: Post java code...

Comment: How are you now displaying the text? Post the java cod e...

Comment: java code posted

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the sentence and add some spaces in between. Here's the sample code...

```
String str = "This is test line 1";
String[] strArray = str.split(" ");

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : strArray) {
     builder.append(s + "   ");
}

String finalString = builder.toString().trim();
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: i have attached two images to the question so that you can get the better idea that actually what my problem is.